# How to discard a local dependency in a maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar-with-dependencies

I have a question about the integration the eclipse and maven.

I have a project `A` with dependencies in project `B` which is itself just a container for a bunch of projects `B-i`.

Project `B` is imported in Eclipse but most of the `B-i` are not imported in eclipse. Sometimes, I want to work on a patch in `B-n`. So I import the `B-n` project and dependency resolving usually works well, that is, project A uses the project `B-n` and recompiles.

Problem happens often when I want to discard the local dependency, close the local project, and make sure that the remote `B-n` from our repository is used by `A` (let's say that the other team patched project `B`).

What is the good and proper "way" to do that kind of patching/ensure that `A` is using the remote/server version of `B-n` and not the previously compiled local jar ?
Removing the local project ? Removing the dependency in the local project ? Will I always have to "clean install" project A when I do such a change ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you do the following:

You have a project `B-n` with a version (say `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`). It is built on some kind of build server.

Then you check it out, built it locally (still with version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`). Now you want to discard your locally built version and refer again to the `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` from the repository (correct me if you did not understand you correctly).

For that, you can purge the local repository by `dependency:purge-local-repository`. You can start this from Eclipse through "Run As -> Maven Build...". See also

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html